# jquery change image source with html5 data attribute

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

i want to change image source with html5 data attribute. I've tried many ways but still can't solve so far, for demonstration here is the code;

**HTML Markup:**

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Default%20Image" data-imgSmall="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Small%20Image" data-imgMedium="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Medium%20Image" data-imgLarge="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Large%20Image" />

<button class="small">Small Image</button>
<button class="medium">Medium Image</button>
<button class="large">Large Image</button>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
var ImgSmall = $('img').data('imgSmall'),
    ImgMedium = $('img').data('imgMedium'),
    ImgLarge = $('img').data('imgLarge'),
    img = $('img');

$('button').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("small")) {
        img.attr('src', ImgSmall);
        alert(ImgSmall);
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass("medium")) {
        img.attr('src', ImgMedium);
        alert(ImgMedium);
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass("large")) {
        img.attr('src', ImgLarge);
        alert(ImgLarge);
    }
});
```

But this code still not working, plz advice where I'm wrong, thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pSs7v/, working example here

Comment: Why don't you cache `img` before you call it three times?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute) :

> All attribute names on HTML elements in HTML documents get
>   ASCII-lowercased automatically

Use lowercase names :

```
var ImgSmall = $('img').data('imgsmall'),
    ImgMedium = $('img').data('imgmedium'),
    ImgLarge = $('img').data('imglarge'),
    img = $('img');
```